# MessageBox in c#.net

Tags: dialog, c#-2.0

How can I display a messagebox like the Microsoft error message in C#.net
The message box should have an `OK` button and an `Show details` button.
The `Show details` button should display the error details.  Is there a built in class for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a standard dialog to do this; you'll have to create your own `Form` and display it with a `ShowDialog`.

You can have the `Click` event of the 'Details' button change the size of the form and toggle the visibility of the details text.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in class available to do this.
you can create a custom form with Ok and Show Details button.
set height and width as per the need.
handle click event for the button with appropriate code.
create an instance of this form and use ShowDialog() method to show the dialog box